# Error in Rudin's proof of the Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Tags: measure-theory

My question concerns the proof of the Monotone Convergence Theorem in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* (3rd ed, Theorem 1.26, p.21).

In the proof $f$ is a extended real-valued non-negative function. Rudin introduces a simple measurable function $s$ such that $0\leq s \leq f$ and a number $c$ such that $0<c<1$ and then further down in the proof claims that "if $f(x)>0$, then $cs(x)<f(x)$, since $c<1$".

But isn't this wrong where $f(x)=\infty$? And doesn't this invalidate the proof?

If my contention is right is there a simple way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Definition $1.16$ it is remarked that simple functions do not take the value $\infty$, so the inequality holds trivially in case that $f(x)=\infty$.